# Math markup, diagrams, etc. -- pointers please

Tags: support, mathjax, markdown

Feeling a bit dumb as I plunge into math.stackexchange.com after many years away from the world of mathematics, but can somebody please provide a very quick tutorial -- list of reference pointers would be sufficient -- for getting math markup on math.stackexchange.com. I can use html sup, sub tags, but how to do the more complex markup like fractions, and even drawing diagrams.

Markdown doesn't do much for math, a far as I can tell, but I could be wrong.

Thanks --oldbie/newbie David

Comment: the site has TeX markup support — so you just need to take a look at some TeX tutorial (sorry, no good source comes to mind now)

Comment: Tried Tex, with $\frac{-b}{2a}$ -- oops, may have forgotten the backslash. OK, will try again.

Comment: btw, we need to answer this question in the FAQ

Comment: I've removed the `meta` tag, since all questions asked on meta.math.se are expected to be `meta`, and added the `tex` tag, since TeX is the system used here to render/display math.

Comment: @Grigory: It is already in the [proposed faq](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/what-should-go-in-the-math-stackexchange-faq/117#117). I will update it to include the answers here shortly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you have to do is find a question that uses the markup you'd like to use, then right click and select show source.

Comment: Duh!  Thanks.  Thought of that, but assumed I'd see html instead. I don't know why I didn't just try it.

Answer (score 5):

To type inline TeX equations, surround the code with `$`'s, e.g.

> `$c = \sqrt{ a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \cos \theta }` ⇒ $c = \sqrt{ a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \cos \theta }$

To put the equation in its own line, surround with `$$`'s, e.g.

> `$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} dx = \frac{\sqrt\pi}2$$` ⇒ $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} dx = \frac{\sqrt\pi}2$$

AMS math environment is also supported, e.g.

> ```
> \begin{align}
>   \cos x &= \frac{\sin 2x}{2 \sin x} \\\\
> \sin^2 x &= \cos^2 x - \cos 2x
> \end{align}
> ```
>
> ⇒
>   \begin{align}
>     \cos x &= \frac{\sin 2x}{2 \sin x} \\
>   \sin^2 x &= \cos^2 x - \cos 2x
>   \end{align}

Note that you need 4 backslashes for a new line. Many times you also need extra backslashes to avoid conflict with Markdown syntax, e.g.

> `$$\alpha^{-1}_{-1} + \beta_{-2}$$` won't work, as `_..._` is interpreted as *italics*.
>
> $$\alpha^{-1}*{-1} + \beta*{-2}$$
>
> Use `$$\alpha^{-1}\_{-1} + \beta\_{-2}$$` instead.
>
> $$\alpha^{-1}_{-1} + \beta_{-2}$$

Comment: The multi-backslash-issue should actually [be solved](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/1119/163)

Answer (score 2):

If you have firefox, go to your address bar and type in "lshort" without the quotes. Read the PDF tutorial on Latex. Actually you don't even have to read it. I just bookmarked pages that have the most used commands and I just refer to them when I need it. But that was the PDF that introduced me to Latex.

Comment: more explicitly: chapter 3 @ http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf (right?)

Comment: Yes sir. But again, I would recommend going back and forth from all the chapters so while your learning the math markup, you can also learn how to format an article or journal entry.

Comment: I would also recommend looking over Kenny's answer for the minor differences when writing on this website rather then TexWorks or similar.