# What is the preferred way to escape LaTeX special characters?

Tags: support, mathjax

Suppose I want to make a matrix. Then I need to end each line with a double backslash, to signify a line break. But Markdown will translate a double back slash into a single backslash, thus confusing JSMath, as I learned while answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4658/what-is-the-probability-of-a-coin-landing-tails-7-times-in-a-row-in-a-series-of-1). On MO, the standard solution is to enclose our LaTeX in backticks, so that Markdown will treat it as code and leave it alone. This apparently doesn't work on math.SE.

I worked around this by typing quadruple backslashes, which Markdown makes into double backslashes, and JSMath then understands as line breaks. Is there a better solution?

Comment: I wonder the same thing.  Triple backslashes worked for me, but I really have no idea what I'm doing.  I just try throwing an extra backslash in whenever it doesn't work.

Comment: See also http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/544/matrices-not-rendered-correctly

Comment: I've tried this [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/370/formatting-sandbox/10208#10208), it seems to work fine now. This old thread was [bumped by @mosa](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/posts/813/revisions), who changed tags from ([meta-tag:bug]) to ([meta-tag:support]). (At first, I did not notice that is is an old question.)

Comment: This question appears to be obsolete because it pertains to JSMath, while our current maths renderer is MathJax.

Comment: While the topic is moot now, I seem to remember discussion on meta that it was not the policy to delete old bug reports (hopefully things get fixed, no reason to forget they once occurred).  As to closing them as "off-topic", it seems less apt than applying some sort of tag "status no-repro" (not reproducible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mathoverflow workaround is further described by KennyTM [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/551/allow-texification-in-code-tags). If you favor that method, upvote his feature-request.

For now, extra backslashes is the simplest solution.